# How to put value into <option data-price> tag from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have an API that show me real time ETH price. I want to put this price into data-price `<option value="ETH" data-price="**HERE**">`

Here is Webhook that takes price

```
let btc = new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade')
let BTCPrice = document.getElementById('BTC-price')

btc.onmessage = (event) => {
  let stockObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
  BTCPrice.innerText = parseFloat(stockObject.p).toFixed(2);
}
```

And here in "data-price" I want to put it

```
<select class="p_btn p-select" name="pSelect" id="pSelect" data-plan="1" tabindex="-98">
   <option data-icon="ico-Ethereum" value="ETH" data-price="1400.08" data-valute="ETH" data-precision="8" valute="Ethereum">
   ...
   ...
</select>
```

The "data-price=1400.08" I wrote manually but I want to make it automatically, either live value, either when page refreshes

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing all the html, but try something like `document.querySelector("theOptionParentSelectSelector option[value=ETH]").setAttribute("data-price",thePrice);`

Comment: @mykaf Its like all html, but I will add something more, that you wrote I tried but I have Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute'). I need only to change "thePrice" and other remains how you wrote?

Comment: If you know, will be better to put in data-price the price of it only once when page is refreshed, or to be it live?

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute')" refers to the element you're attempting to set the attribute on. What does your code look like for setting the data-price attribute? Obviously you'd have to modify what I wrote to match your selectors.

Comment: @mykaf I get it, this select code I found on internet and I am trying to do it for my fun project. I don't have code for setting it, but I am trying to do it and I asked how can I do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to make it, you just need to write

```
document.querySelector("#ID_OF_SELECT option[value=VALUE_FROM_OPTION]").setAttribute("data-price", thePrice;
```